# How to dose (inject) chlorine solution straight into closed piping?

Tags: plumbing

I'm planning a DIY project using a typical RV water pump. I want to supply sodium hypochlorite solution into the water right after it passes through the pump to ensure an uniform concentration at a fixed flow.

At high scale there are dosing pumps of course which dose the liquid by pulsations. However, how can I do it at home scale? I'm seeing a bunch of small peristaltic pumps rated at mL / min which seem to be used on aquariums but they are probably meant for open systems. Can they be used for closed and slightly pressurized systems? If not, what could I use for home scale?

Comment: My well guy uses a peristaltic pump to put the chlorine into an open tank then it is pumped into the closed system, he said this was the safest method. I only know about them because I have wired 3 for him. There was a pump and a monitor if the level was outside the safe range the pump in the tank was turned off if it was safe the pressure switch turned the pump off. It may have been a requirement I know 1 was a multi family dwelling and the other a rental not sure about the 3rd.

Answer (score 1):

On the home scale, there are chlorine injection pumps. I constructed from the local plumbing supply's "plans" and products such a system. The house water (well sourced) is under pressure and the dosing pump injects with sufficient force to overcome that pressure. Additionally, there is a valve at the interface of the chlorine feed point and the house feed water pipe.

I'd expect that an aquarium version would not manage the pressure. The dosing pumps can be pricey, though, even the home scale stuff.

The complete home system includes another expensive item, a flow sensor, which triggers the PulsaFeeder™ when there is movement in the system. I've since discovered far less expensive versions, but the one I have has proven to be reliable.

It's a good idea to have the injection point downstream of the pump. Some DIY systems in my neighborhood used a port cut into the pump priming cap and Bernoulli's principle to create chlorine injection. The high concentration at that location eventually causes corrosion, requiring an expensive pump part replacement.

As you've noted, you'll be building into a pressure system, which means that you'd have back-feed valves in the circuit. At the very least, the injection nozzle is a back-feed valve.

Answer (score 1):

There's something called a "venturi fertilizer injector" that requires no outside power or metering pump. It relies on the [venturi effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venturi_effect) to suck a liquid into a piping system as another liquid flows by. You may be able to adjust flow with a needle valve. Note that if flow stops while the main pipe is under pressure, water can back up into the additive's container unless the venturi is equipped with a check valve.